# Access Run-time Error 3134

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following code that I have read and made changes to for the last 3 hours and just can seam to get it working.

The error I get is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

```
Private Sub AddRecord_Click()

'Add the form details to the table

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO (Transactions (tDate,  category, transAmount, transDescription) " & _
    "VALUES & (" & _
    "'" & Me.txt_tDate & "', " & _
    "'" & Me.cmb_Category & "', " & _
    "'" & txt_TransAmount & "', " & _
    "'" & Me.txt_transDescription & "' " & _
    ")"


End Sub
```

The form has 4 fields as above with the tDate being set to Date() by default and all others as short text or number.

Any advice welcome.

Thanks

Comment: See this for instructions:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/122139.  The important thing is to use `Debug.Print` to put the final version of your query in the Immediate window; from there you can take it ordinary query builder and start trouble shooting.

Comment: Great link and answer @Smandoli. Goes straight to bookmarks and I'm never gonna have to type this stuff again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first `&` in this line:

```
"VALUES & (" & _
```

So it is:

```
"VALUES (" & _
```

Answer (score 0):

Further, hardly all values are text, thus:

```
"#" & Format(Me.txt_tDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#, " & _
"'" & Me.cmb_Category & "', " & _
"" & Str(txt_TransAmount) & ", " & _
"'" & Me.txt_transDescription & "' " & _
```

where Str will convert a decimal value to a string with dot as the decimal separator.